# How do I correct this python output?

Tags: python

I've got the rest of the code right for some reason I keep getting output 16, can anyone help?

I keep getting output 16

here's my code:

```py
user_num1 = int(input())
user_num2 = int(input())

if user_num1 < 0:
    print ('user_num1 is negative.')
if user_num2 > 15:
    print ('user_num2 is 4')
else:
    print ('user_num2 is less than or equal to 15.')


print('user_num2 is', user_num2)
```

[image]

Comment: When it is > 15, you are supposed to set it to `4`, not print anything.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Although the expected output indicates that it's still supposed to print it.

Comment: @BriS please no [images of code, errors or output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Type it in/copy paste the input and output as text. Thanks. Why are editors continuing to inline this image? It's just a waste of people's limited bandwidth and screen real estate. Images should be opt-in by clicking (and this one doesn't need to exist in the first place).

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it is confusing. But not printing anything when it is < 15 while assigning `user_num2 = 4` and keeping the final `print('user_num2 is', user_num2)` should produce the correct output in both cases (even though the instructions do not say to print it at the end).

Answer (score 1):

Read Question Carefully.You are doing wrong.Its written to assign user_num2 = 4 and print 'user_num2 is 4'

```
user_num1 = int(input())
user_num2 = int(input())

if user_num1 < 0:
    print ('user_num1 is negative.')
if user_num2 > 15:
    user_num2 = 4
    print ('user_num2 is 4')
else:
    print ('user_num2 is less than or equal to 15.')
    print('user_num2 is',user_num2)
```

Comment: It also says that the expected output is `user_num2 is 4`. So it seems like the instructions aren't complete (or they didn't copy all of it).

Comment: Please take a look at the expected output. The last one contains ``user_num2 is 15``, which this code cannot produce.

Comment: You are having the input statement twice for user_num1